# Request Entity Coming as Null when upgrade to 3.1 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-3.1

EDITED

I am new here. So if this is a repeat question please forgive me.

We are having issue when we migrated to dotnet core 3.1 from 2.0. Explained as follows:

First our entity is like this

```
class Student {
      string StudentId 
}
```

So when we used our controller like this

```cs
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudentByIdAsync([FromBody] Student studentrequest)
```

we never got `Studentrequest` as null in **2.0** if we sent the entity as 
`{"studentId":1}` or `{"studentId":"1"}`

both worked fine.

But in **3.1** we are getting request as **null** if we give the request as  `{"studentId":1}`.
Our UI is based on this format and it is a separate external team. And we have lot of work based on this. 
So neither they nor us are willing to change.

One more point is that earlier we used `addMvc()` in `Startup.cs`, but now we are using `addControllers()`.
Can this be a cause for this?

Can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, `AddControllers` is for API. Get `AddMvc` back.

Comment: There are a few changes when updating your code to 3.1. Have you gone through the upgrade docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30

Comment: @Rosco , yes we followed the documentation you provided to migrate from 2.0 to 3.1. From then on wards we are getting the issue.

Comment: @JohnyL yes we would also like to have AddMvc back

Comment: You said your entity is `class Student` but your controller action has `Studentrequest`.

Comment: What JSON deserialization library are you using? ASP.NET Core 3+ uses Microsoft's new JSON library instead of `Newtonsoft.Json` - I suspect it's refusing to match the camelCase `studentId` JSON property to your PascalCase `StudentId` class member.

Comment: @Dai is right. Match the parameter name with the json property key and it should work. You can choose wich Json library you want to use in your Startup.cs. The new one is faster

Comment: Thank you @Dai. I have corrected my function declaration.

Comment: @Krusty, it was mistake on my part as i gave have omitted a word by mistake. But the issue was w.r.t. the formatter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dai's Comment :

> What JSON deserialization library are you using? ASP.NET Core 3+ uses Microsoft's new JSON library instead of Newtonsoft.Json - I suspect it's refusing to match the camelCase studentId JSON property to your PascalCase StudentId class member. – [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)

I was able to understand that it was change in the implementation from NewtonSoft.Json as formatter in dotnet Core 2.0 to System.Text.Json in 3.X.

After looking around on a solution i found [this post on medium.](https://medium.com/cloudnimble/switching-to-system-text-json-in-net-core-3-0-not-so-fast-4c577a21298b)

The solution to prevent my error was to add **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** nuget to your solution and integrate the following or similar lines in your startup.cs configure method:

```
        _ = services.AddControllers(options =>
          {
              options.Filters.Add(typeof(WithHeaderHandlerAttribute));
          })
           .AddNewtonsoftJson(
            options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new
            CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()).AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true);
```

Hope this helps someone else.